# passing parameter value to a jquery function from React code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a state variable declared as:

```
    this.state = {
         userId: this.props.uid

    }
```

We need to adapt a jquery command so it can receive this.state.userId from inside a react function. Is there a general way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery command"?

Comment: this.state should be declared as `this.state = { userId: this.props.uid }`

Answer (score 1):

Simples:

**React**

```
render() {
    return (<div id="user" data-userId={this.state.userId}></div>);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#user").data('userId');
```

Then you need to do the victory dance because reasons. (<= very important)

Following up to our comments, getting user data via AJAX with react using fetch

```
componentWillMount = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`users/${this.state.userId}`, {Authentication: `Bearer ${authToken}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    if (response.status ===200) {
        //do better checks and stuff 
        try{
            const user = await response.json();
            this.setState({
                user: user,
            });
        } catch(e){
            console.error('error with your response: '+e.message);
        }
     } else {
         console.error('response status was '+response.status);
     }
}
```

I'd do something a little more robust than this but this is the general idea. If you've never used fetch before I'd recommend looking into cors and that can be a right pain!

Also if you're looking for some a lot, lot more organised and 'app like' I'd looking into redux, redux saga, redux persist and redux form. Great packages!! But anyway. Moral of the story is: kill jQuery with fire and stick to react (y).

Comment: but, is it possible to call 
            $("#user").data('userId');
from inside jsx code?

Comment: Dunno, depends on your setup. If you have a component rendering to an element and a jquery script outside of the component on the dom then this would work. However!! when react boots and does it's ting wrapping in `$(document).ready()` won't fire off events for when react re-renders. What are you trying to achieve because you could probably do it without jquery and just use react.

Comment: Someone left us a jquery form that will use that id to get user information to be displayed through this form. Do you think your idea will work in this case? thanks a lot

Comment: probably not, I'd suggest using `fetch` to get the user's information from a REST type endpoint. I'll update my answer